# FTP with Swift 4/5 (with/without extra framework)

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

First of all: I know about the security concerns regarding ftp, so please no discussion about this here - ftp has to be used.

My app has to log into a server with ftp (with username/password), search for and download a file, delete it from the server, then upload an edited version.

I've been searching for tutorials on how to even get a connection to a server via ftp but all I found were Apple's documentation from 2012 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html) and their documentation about the different functions [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork) (and a bunch of weird "Swift FTP" biking videos on youtube...). Every other example I found (usually <2015) uses some additional framework or library but there don't seem to be any proper tutorial for Swift 5 or even Swift 4.

Is it even still possible to use FTP with Swift 5 (is it still supported?) and if so, how? Or is there simply no point trying to get any of Apple's stuff to work and better to just use an extra framework like [FileProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider)?

Comment: The documentation from 2012 is still valid. Most of the API is deprecated but it still works. It's possible to write a Swift 5 version without any additional frameworks. You need a `socket` related operation to send the raw FTP commands and a `stream` related operation to transfer data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are any of the important parts deprecated too or is everything (logging in, downloading, searching, uploading) still possible and working? Slightly off-topic: From your experience, is it still worth getting into it or would you recommend starting with a custom framework/library?

Comment: The entire  `CFFTP...` API is deprecated. It's used for example to read the contents of a directory. The [`Stream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/stream) and BSD socket API is not deprecated. The subject is not trivial, but the Apple documentation (although in ObjC) is a good starting point.

Comment: I see. Is there an alternative for searching a directory? I'm currently trying to get into it but I don't even know how to start and my non-existing knowledge of ObjC doesn't help. I simply can't find any good information about Swift - do you happen to know a decent tutorial?

Comment: I don't think there are any tutorials. For my purpose I translated the ObjC code into Swift and the C API of BSD socket can be used in Swift with only a few adjustments.

Comment: Oh, now I understand why others would rather use the extra library instead of translating stuff between ObjC and Swift. Thanks for you answers!

Comment: Just a quick update: I'm currently using [FileProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider) - it's the only library I found that wasn't last updated 1+ years ago. It still works but unfortunately it's a bit buggy: Every function I've tested so far (downloading/reading files on my ftp server, see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56113593/2016165)) is being called twice and it doesn't look like the author is still working on the library or fixing bugs.

Comment: I don't know the library, sorry.

Comment: The comment was simply meant as an update for everyone who should come across this question. ;)

Comment: @Neph Is there any news? I was looking for FTP issues without framework with Swift 5.0. One of my friend used 'rebekka' pod for FTP. It works. But as I wrote above I am looking for FTP issues without frameworks with Swift 5.0

Comment: @mannyCalavera I also looked at `rebekka` last year but didn't use it because it's for Swift 2 - I'm surprised it still works. And no, no news, as I haven't worked on the app lately. Plus, I'm using the socket library as stated below, which is working perfectly fine and unless a new Swift version completely breaks that library, I don't think I'm going to change it again.

Comment: @Neph thanks. Is it possible you to share this socket library with me?

Comment: @mannyCalavera You can find the link in the answer I posted.

Comment: BlueSocket, okay.

Answer (score 1):

At first I was using [FileProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider), unfortunately the library is pretty buggy currently, with functions being called twice (which you can kind of prevent by using a "firstTimeCalled" bool check) and if the server's slow(-ish), you also might not get e.g. the full list of files in a directory because FileProvider stops receiving answers before the server's actually done.

I haven't found any other FTP libraries for Swift that work (and are still supported), so now I'm using [BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket) (which is able to open sockets, send commands to the server and receive commands from it) and built my own small library that can send/receive,... files (using the FTP codes) around it.