# Download multiple files from FTP server (using sockets)

Tags: swift, sockets, ftp

I want to download multiple files from an FTP server using the sockets directly. I'm using Swift 5 with the [BlueSocket](https://github.com/Kitura/BlueSocket) library, which is basically a wrapper, so the commands are the same as if I did everything through e.g. Windows console.

FTP commands:

```
Login + connect cmdSocket
cmdSocket send: PASV
cmdSocket receive: 227 Entering Passive Mode
cmdSocket send: TYPE I
cmdSocket receive: 200 Type set to I
Connect dataSocket to Passive Mode IP/port
cmdSocket send: CWD myFolder
cmdSocket receive: 250 CWD command successful
```

Looping through all the files:

```
cmdSocket send: RETR myFileX
cmdSocket receive: Either "150 Downloading in BINARY file" or "125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting"
dataSocket: Receive data and save it to storage
cmdSocket receive: 226 Transfer complete
```

This works fine for the first file ("myFile1") but everything changes in the second loop iteration ("myFile2"):

```
cmdSocket send: RETR myFile2
cmdSocket receive: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```

Now the dataSocket won't return any bytes and sometimes it also receives "425 Cannot open data connection." in addition to "150". I tried to use "myFile1" twice but with the same result.

I'm guessing that the order is off but what is wrong exactly? Do I have to change the type for every file, so within the loop? Do I have to open a new data socket for every file or maybe send some "reset" command after "226" is received for the first file?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in the parts you didn't talk about, the data connection. You're assuming that your problem opening the data connection has something to do with the command order, and nothing to do with the data connection!

Comment: @user253751 What would you suggest? The first file always finishes downloading, so I assumed that the data connection itself was fine and that something was missing at the end (like a command that resets the connection). A while ago I also used Apache's FTP library (Java, not Swift), which provides easy functions to use (something like "retrieveFileStream") but it uses the same order: 1. Login, 2. Passive Mode, 3. File Type, 4. Change folder, 5. Loop over files. At the end you had to call `completePendingCommand()` for cleanup, so maybe that's missing here but I don't know what this would be.

Comment: I suggest that there is something wrong with the second data connection. Considering the server says it can't open the second data connection. Do you need to send PASV before every connection? Not sure.

Comment: @user253751 The "425" code only shows up in 1 out of maybe 10 tries. The other 9 times there's no exception or error, it's just that no actual data is returned (0 bytes). BlueSocket provides a check for sockets (`dataSocket.isConnected`), which I just added  before I send the `RETR` command: It's `true`, even for the second loop iteration, so the connection is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by "still" there? I thought you had to open a new data connection for every command?

Comment: @user253751 Every command, what do you mean? Do you have to open a new data socket for every time you send the `RETR` command? Currently I open a connection to the data socket only once, directly after I switch to binary mode (please see the first code paragraph in my question) and I use the same data socket for every file. I added a check before `RETR` and apparently the connection to the data socket was still open the second time but only returned 0 bytes.

Comment: Well that's what I *thought* you had to do.

Comment: @Neph "*Do you have to open a new data socket for every time you send the `RETR` command?*" - under the default `STREAM` transmission mode, yes. You will have to use a `MODE` command to change that. "*I use the same data socket for every file*" - that will not work under `STREAM` mode.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks to you too, I switched stuff around and now it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, FTP uses the `STREAM` transmission mode on data transfers. Under `STREAM` mode, End-Of-File is signaled by closing the data connection.  As such, you can send only 1 file per data connection in `STREAM` mode.

To work around that, you will have to either:

- issue a new `PORT`/`PASV` command to establish a new data connection for each individual file.
- issue a `MODE` command to switch to `BLOCK` or `COMPRESSED` transmission mode before transferring files. Both modes do not signal EOF by closing the data connection, but rather by sending an explicit marker over the data connection at the end of each file, thus allowing multiple files to be transferred over a single data connection.

For more details, read the official FTP protocol specification, [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), specifically sections 3.3 "DATA CONNECTION MANAGEMENT" and 3.4 "TRANSMISSION MODES":

```
3.3.  DATA CONNECTION MANAGEMENT

      Default Data Connection Ports:  All FTP implementations must
      support use of the default data connection ports, and only the
      User-PI may initiate the use of non-default ports.

      Negotiating Non-Default Data Ports:   The User-PI may specify a
      non-default user side data port with the PORT command.  The
      User-PI may request the server side to identify a non-default
      server side data port with the PASV command.  Since a connection
      is defined by the pair of addresses, either of these actions is
      enough to get a different data connection, still it is permitted
      to do both commands to use new ports on both ends of the data
      connection.

      Reuse of the Data Connection:  When using the stream mode of data
      transfer the end of the file must be indicated by closing the
      connection.  This causes a problem if multiple files are to be
      transfered in the session, due to need for TCP to hold the
      connection record for a time out period to guarantee the reliable
      communication.  Thus the connection can not be reopened at once.

         There are two solutions to this problem.  The first is to
         negotiate a non-default port.  The second is to use another
         transfer mode.

         A comment on transfer modes.  The stream transfer mode is
         inherently unreliable, since one can not determine if the
         connection closed prematurely or not.  The other transfer modes
         (Block, Compressed) do not close the connection to indicate the
         end of file.  They have enough FTP encoding that the data
         connection can be parsed to determine the end of the file.
         Thus using these modes one can leave the data connection open
         for multiple file transfers.
```

```
   3.4.  TRANSMISSION MODES

      The next consideration in transferring data is choosing the
      appropriate transmission mode.  There are three modes: one which
      formats the data and allows for restart procedures; one which also
      compresses the data for efficient transfer; and one which passes
      the data with little or no processing.  In this last case the mode
      interacts with the structure attribute to determine the type of
      processing.  In the compressed mode, the representation type
      determines the filler byte.

      All data transfers must be completed with an end-of-file (EOF)
      which may be explicitly stated or implied by the closing of the
      data connection.  For files with record structure, all the
      end-of-record markers (EOR) are explicit, including the final one.
      For files transmitted in page structure a "last-page" page type is
      used.

      NOTE:  In the rest of this section, byte means "transfer byte"
      except where explicitly stated otherwise.

      For the purpose of standardized transfer, the sending host will
      translate its internal end of line or end of record denotation
      into the representation prescribed by the transfer mode and file
      structure, and the receiving host will perform the inverse
      translation to its internal denotation.  An IBM Mainframe record
      count field may not be recognized at another host, so the
      end-of-record information may be transferred as a two byte control
      code in Stream mode or as a flagged bit in a Block or Compressed
      mode descriptor.  End-of-line in an ASCII or EBCDIC file with no
      record structure should be indicated by <CRLF> or <NL>,
      respectively.  Since these transformations imply extra work for
      some systems, identical systems transferring non-record structured
      text files might wish to use a binary representation and stream
      mode for the transfer.

      The following transmission modes are defined in FTP:

      3.4.1.  STREAM MODE

         The data is transmitted as a stream of bytes.  There is no
         restriction on the representation type used; record structures
         are allowed.

         In a record structured file EOR and EOF will each be indicated
         by a two-byte control code.  The first byte of the control code
         will be all ones, the escape character.  The second byte will
         have the low order bit on and zeros elsewhere for EOR and the
         second low order bit on for EOF; that is, the byte will have
         value 1 for EOR and value 2 for EOF.  EOR and EOF may be
         indicated together on the last byte transmitted by turning both
         low order bits on (i.e., the value 3).  If a byte of all ones
         was intended to be sent as data, it should be repeated in the
         second byte of the control code.

         If the structure is a file structure, the EOF is indicated by
         the sending host closing the data connection and all bytes are
         data bytes.

      3.4.2.  BLOCK MODE

         The file is transmitted as a series of data blocks preceded by
         one or more header bytes.  The header bytes contain a count
         field, and descriptor code.  The count field indicates the
         total length of the data block in bytes, thus marking the
         beginning of the next data block (there are no filler bits).
         The descriptor code defines:  last block in the file (EOF) last
         block in the record (EOR), restart marker (see the Section on
         Error Recovery and Restart) or suspect data (i.e., the data
         being transferred is suspected of errors and is not reliable).
         This last code is NOT intended for error control within FTP.
         It is motivated by the desire of sites exchanging certain types
         of data (e.g., seismic or weather data) to send and receive all
         the data despite local errors (such as "magnetic tape read
         errors"), but to indicate in the transmission that certain
         portions are suspect).  Record structures are allowed in this
         mode, and any representation type may be used.

         The header consists of the three bytes.  Of the 24 bits of
         header information, the 16 low order bits shall represent byte
         count, and the 8 high order bits shall represent descriptor
         codes as shown below.


         Block Header

            +----------------+----------------+----------------+
            | Descriptor     |    Byte Count                   |
            |         8 bits |                      16 bits    |
            +----------------+----------------+----------------+


         The descriptor codes are indicated by bit flags in the
         descriptor byte.  Four codes have been assigned, where each
         code number is the decimal value of the corresponding bit in
         the byte.

            Code     Meaning

             128     End of data block is EOR
              64     End of data block is EOF
              32     Suspected errors in data block
              16     Data block is a restart marker

         With this encoding, more than one descriptor coded condition
         may exist for a particular block.  As many bits as necessary
         may be flagged.

         The restart marker is embedded in the data stream as an
         integral number of 8-bit bytes representing printable
         characters in the language being used over the control
         connection (e.g., default--NVT-ASCII).  <SP> (Space, in the
         appropriate language) must not be used WITHIN a restart marker.

         For example, to transmit a six-character marker, the following
         would be sent:

            +--------+--------+--------+
            |Descrptr|  Byte count     |
            |code= 16|             = 6 |
            +--------+--------+--------+

            +--------+--------+--------+
            | Marker | Marker | Marker |
            | 8 bits | 8 bits | 8 bits |
            +--------+--------+--------+

            +--------+--------+--------+
            | Marker | Marker | Marker |
            | 8 bits | 8 bits | 8 bits |
            +--------+--------+--------+


      3.4.3.  COMPRESSED MODE

         There are three kinds of information to be sent:  regular data,
         sent in a byte string; compressed data, consisting of
         replications or filler; and control information, sent in a
         two-byte escape sequence.  If n>0 bytes (up to 127) of regular
         data are sent, these n bytes are preceded by a byte with the
         left-most bit set to 0 and the right-most 7 bits containing the
         number n.

         Byte string:

             1       7                8                     8
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |0|       n     | |    d(1)       | ... |      d(n)     |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                                          ^             ^
                                          |---n bytes---|
                                              of data

            String of n data bytes d(1),..., d(n)
            Count n must be positive.

         To compress a string of n replications of the data byte d, the
         following 2 bytes are sent:

         Replicated Byte:

              2       6               8
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |1 0|     n     | |       d       |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

         A string of n filler bytes can be compressed into a single
         byte, where the filler byte varies with the representation
         type.  If the type is ASCII or EBCDIC the filler byte is <SP>
         (Space, ASCII code 32, EBCDIC code 64).  If the type is Image
         or Local byte the filler is a zero byte.

         Filler String:

              2       6
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            |1 1|     n     |
            +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

         The escape sequence is a double byte, the first of which is the
         escape byte (all zeros) and the second of which contains
         descriptor codes as defined in Block mode.  The descriptor
         codes have the same meaning as in Block mode and apply to the
         succeeding string of bytes.

         Compressed mode is useful for obtaining increased bandwidth on
         very large network transmissions at a little extra CPU cost.
         It can be most effectively used to reduce the size of printer
         files such as those generated by RJE hosts.
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it okay to do `CWD` and `TYPE I` right in the beginning and only repeat `PASV` + new data socket + `RETR` for every file, as long as I keep the command socket open?

Comment: Yes, your command socket has to be open all the time, that is your ftp session.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I know that I need the command socket. ;) What I'm not 100% sure about is the exact order if there are multiple files, so what has to be done for every file (apart from `PASV` and obviously `RETR`) and what applies to the whole session (= as long as the command socket is open).

Comment: PASV RETR use new data socket, PASV RETR use new datasocket, ...

Comment: Is there no FTP library you can use instead of this bluesocket thing. Makes your life complicated and having to know about FTP inner working. Point is, you want to transfer files. There must be libraries for that no ? I would never implement FTP like this myself.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I used to use a different library that provided easy to use functions but it was pretty buggy and the author wasn't working on it anymore, so I switched to BlueSocket. There aren't a lot of other FTP libraries for Swift 4/5 and they're even older (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56056860/2016165) question) and/or use ObjC. This works and I built my own little library around it, so I'm fine with it.

Comment: @Neph, if I was in any way helpfull please upvote my answer or mark it as solution.

Comment: @Neph technically yes, you can issue a single `CWD` comma d, and *should* be able to issue a single `TYPE` command, before then `RETR`'ing multiple files. But it is not unheard of for clients to send a new `TYPE` command for each file, either. Use whatever works for your server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I switched the code around and now it's working, so thanks for the tip too! :) Dealing with a different problem now (have to call the library's function multiple times to get the full 9mb of data) but that's, well, a different problem. I left `TYPE` outside the loop (after `CWD`) and haven't tested it inside yet. What would you recommend where to put it? Just leave it outside if it's working? I'm guessing there's no "dos and don'ts" list for FTP, is there?

Comment: I would recommend using a commonly-used FTP client, like FileZilla, and see what it sends for your scenario, and then replicate that same command set in your code.

Answer (score 0):

FTP works like the following:
You setup a TCP connection to the FTP server.
Over that socket you can send commands, and the server will reply over that same socket.
You can use the port command :

```
Client: PORT 192,168,1,2,7,139  //The client wants the server to send to port number 1931 on the client machine. 7 and 139 in hex = 078B = 1931
Server: 200 PORT command successful.    
Client: RETR Yoyodyne.TXT   //Download "Yoyodyne.TXT."
Server: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for Yoyodyne.TXT.The server now connects out from its port 20 on 172.16.62.36 to port 1931 on 192.168.1.2.
Server: 226 Transfer completed. //That succeeded, so the data is now sent over the established data connection. And the connection is closed
```

So a new RETR first needs a new PORT command. Or if not, it might be that the previous port command is persistent. But you will have to connect again.

Each file has its own socket where its data will be send/received. and the socket is closed after each file is sent. So you need a new socket each time, and a new connect.

more details here :
https://www.ncftp.com/libncftp/doc/ftp_overview.html

Comment: "*So a new RETR first needs a new PORT command*" - that is required only by *default*, but the client can change that behavior via a `MODE` command. Also, you can use *either* the `PORT` command (server establishes data connection to the client) or the `PASV` command (client establishes data connection to the server). `PASV` is usually preferred, as `PORT` requires port forwarding be configured to work correctly when the client is behind a NAT router.

Comment: I know, I simplified the explanation a bit and provided the link for more detailed information. In that link the difference between the port command and the pasv command is explained. I figured that part was not needed because the op is able to post one file.

Comment: I don't know of any specific ports on the two FTP servers I'm using, that's why I'm using `PASV` (see the commands in my question).

Comment: Then call PASV for each file : Client: PASV
Server: Entering Passive Mode (172,16,62,36,133,111) The last 2 numbers contain the port 133 in hex followed with 111 in hex, but them together, there is your port number in hex. It is very well explained in the link I provided. Except for how to translate those 2 numbers in the port but it is trivial really.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I know how to open a new passive connection and connect a data socket to it, that was luckily never the problem. As you can see in my question, I also only use `PASV`. User253751's, your and Remy Lebeau's comments that every `RETR` needs its own data socket is the reason why it wasn't working - `isConnected` in the library says that the data socket is still connected but there's also another function (`remoteConnectionClosed`) and according to that one the socket is really unusable after sending `226`. This doesn't depend on sending `PORT` though, as it was pointed out already.

Comment: The reason for that is that in a TCP situation both ends need to close the socket. As you did not close the socket but the peer did you see that you are still connected. Closing a socket means that you on your end will no longer send anything on the socket.